# Explode an array of structs with element position in HIVE

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, hive, hiveql

Does anybody know if there is something similar to **lateral view posexplode** but with array of struct? I want to explode an array of structs to multiple rows while computing the position of the element. I use **lateral view inline** to explode but it does not give element position.

For example in data I have smth like:
[{"group":A,"score":20},{"group":B,"score":30}]

I would like to see the table:

```
nb group score
1 A 20
2 B 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  lateral view posexplode, then access struct fields using dot:

```
select t.*,
       e.pos, --position
       --struct fields
       e.st.group,
       e.st.score 
  from table_name t 
       lateral view outer posexplode (t.my_array_of_struct) e as pos, st
```